# How can one maintain multiple lists of array indexes whose values are used by a function that outputs an array of results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, neural-network

Building a sparsely-connected neural network from scratch in Javascript.

I have a 2d array. Each object in the second dimension (array[x][y]) holds 2 arrays, starts:[] and ends:[]. Each object in these arrays holds value and weight. Ends are incoming connections. Starts are outgoing connections. So, when a "synapse" is created, it is stored in the starts array of the pre-synaptic neuron and the ends array of the post-synaptic neuron. (Neurons aren't actual objects, just cells in the array).

My current predict function:

```
predict(array, values){
    var result = [];
    if(values.length <= array[0].length){
      for(var a = 0; a < values.length; a++){
        for(var b = 0; b < array[0][a].starts.length; b++){
          array[0][a].starts[b].value = values[a];
        }
      }

      for(var c = 0; c < array.length; c++){
        for(var d = 0; d < array[c].length; d++){
          var sum = 0;
          for(var e = 0; e < array[c][d].ends.length; e++){
            sum += array[c][d].ends[e].weight * array[c][d].ends[e].value;
          }
        }
        for(var f = 0; f < array[c][d].starts[f].length; f++){
          array[c][d].starts[f].value = util.sigmoid(sum);
        }
      }

      for(var g = 0; g < array[array.length-1].length; g++){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var h = 0; h < array[array.length-1][g].ends.length; h++){
          sum += util.sigmoid(array[array.length-1][g].ends[h].weight * array[array.length-1][g].ends[h].value;
        }
        result.push(util.sigmoid(sum);
      }
    }
    else{
      log.add("### PREDICT ### Not enough input neurons. Afferent growth signal.");
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works fine if I'm looking for a boolean output (0 or 1). I, however, have multiple outputs and I only want to back-propagate through the chain of weights that is relevant to each output. I'm aware that the same weight will appear in multiple chains - this is something that I want to test. I've read somewhere that actual back-propagation is inefficient, but I think that it's required here.

I would like to avoid looping through the entire network again to find the chain if possible. Also, if you see anything wrong with my predict function, please let me know!

For some context, I've made a little game. The game has a player box and a target box. I would like to input playerX, playerY, targetX, and targetY. Outputs are Down, Left, Up, and Right (directions the player can move). So, if input is 1, 1, 5, 5 ... and the "Up" output node is "heaviest", I want to correct the weights in the chain that led to the Up output and reinforce the weights in the chain that led to the Down output.